# jQuery get child value by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="pane">
 <h3>
  <input type=hidden id="comm_id" value="{$comment.id}">
  <label id="comm_name" onclick="this.style.display='none';document.getElementById('comm_name_edit_view').style.display='';document.getElementById('comm_name_edit').value=this.innerHTML;">{$comment.writer_name}</label>
  <div id="comm_name_edit_view" style="display:none;">
   <input type=text id="comm_name_edit" value="{$comment.writer_name}">&nbsp;
   <button onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none';document.getElementById('comm_name').innerHTML=getElementById('comm_name_edit').value;document.getElementById('comm_name').style.display='';">حفظ</button>
  </div>
 </h3>

 <p>
  <label id="comm_content" onclick="this.style.display='none';document.getElementById('comm_content_edit_view').style.display='';document.getElementById('comm_content_edit').value=this.innerHTML;">{$comment.comment}</label>
  <div id="comm_content_edit_view" style="display:none;">
   <textarea type=text id="comm_content_edit">{$comment.comment}</textarea>
   <button onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none';document.getElementById('comm_content').innerHTML=getElementById('comm_content_edit').value;document.getElementById('comm_content').style.display='';">حفظ</button>
  </div>
 </p>
 <p><a href="#" class="btn-delete">delete</a> | <a href="#" class="btn-approve">approve</a> | <a href="#" class="btn-spam">spam</a></p>
</div>
```

and the following jQuery (I'm bad at jQuery)

```
jQuery(function(){
        $(".pane:even").addClass("alt");

        $(".pane .btn-delete").click(function(){

 var x=SOMETHING;        
         $(this).parents(".pane").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
         .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow")
         return false;
        }); ..... etc
```

In the `var x=SOMETHING;`, I want to be able to get the value of the `input` box with ID of `comm_id` in that pane. Is it somehow possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have multiple panes? That what it sounds like...and ID attributes must be unique on a document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the input by using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get to the `<div class="pane">` then [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the input inside, like this:

```
$(".pane .btn-delete").click(function(){
  var x = $(this).closest(".pane").find(".comm_id").val(); 
  //use x
  //animations...
});
```

Note the change of `id` to `class` to be valid for multiple panes, your `<input>` should look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" class="comm_id" value="{$comment.id}">
```

Comment: Thanks :) , and how to get the innerHTML value of the var z = $(this).closest(".pane").find(".comm_content").something ??

Comment: Yup, use `.text()` there: `$(this).closest(".pane").find(".comm_content").text();`, again change it to `class="comm_content"` to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = $("#comm_id").val();
```

EDIT:

actually, you don't even need to select it by ID: you could just use

```
var x = $( "input[type=hidden]", $( this ).parents(".pane") ).val();
```

this would solve the problem if you have several fragments of code like that.

Comment: This isn't a valid approach, since you can tell by `$(".pane:even")` that it's repeating, so an `id` isn't appropriate here - for your edit, that's not valid either, since `this` refers to the clicked button, not the div...so it'd find no input.

Comment: @Nick Craver in which way `$(".pane:even")` tells you that there isn't a single `$(".pane .btn-delete")`? Edited my answer anyway to account for that.

Comment: It indicates there are multiple panes in a striped style (the `.alt` class), so that `id="comm_id"` isn't unique...which is a problem.  For your edit, the `<input>` isn't *inside* the `.btn-delete` anchor, so that won't find any elements.